# Where can I find mad (mean absolute deviation) in scipy?

Tags: python, scipy, statsmodels

It seems scipy once provided a function `mad` to calculate the mean absolute deviation for a set of numbers:

http://projects.scipy.org/scipy/browser/trunk/scipy/stats/models/utils.py?rev=3473

However, I can not find it anywhere in current versions of scipy. Of course it is possible to just copy the old code from repository but I prefer to use scipy's version. Where can I find it, or has it been replaced or removed?

Comment: Sorry, a search in the [github repository](https://github.com/scipy/scipy) gave me nothing.

Comment: Is it so hard to write it from scratch?

Comment: @RomanSusi, no, but as I stated in the question, that is not the point.

Comment: Beware, "MAD" usually refers to the "Median absolute deviation", **not** the mean difference:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_absolute_difference

Answer (score 63, accepted):

[EDIT] Since this keeps on getting downvoted: I know that *median* absolute deviation is a more commonly-used statistic, but the questioner asked for *mean* absolute deviation, and here's how to do it:

```
from numpy import mean, absolute

def mad(data, axis=None):
    return mean(absolute(data - mean(data, axis)), axis)
```

Answer (score 37):

For what its worth, I use this for MAD:

```
def mad(arr):
    """ Median Absolute Deviation: a "Robust" version of standard deviation.
        Indices variabililty of the sample.
        https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Median_absolute_deviation 
    """
    arr = np.ma.array(arr).compressed() # should be faster to not use masked arrays.
    med = np.median(arr)
    return np.median(np.abs(arr - med))
```

Comment: Nice solution; however, the questioner was asking about the **mean** absolute deviation. You've provided the **median** absolute deviation.

Answer (score 31):

The current version of [statsmodels](http://www.statsmodels.org/stable/index.html) has `mad` in `statsmodels.robust`:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> from statsmodels import robust
>>> a = np.matrix( [
...     [ 80, 76, 77, 78, 79, 81, 76, 77, 79, 84, 75, 79, 76, 78 ],
...     [ 66, 69, 76, 72, 79, 77, 74, 77, 71, 79, 74, 66, 67, 73 ]
...  ], dtype=float )
>>> robust.mad(a, axis=1)
array([ 2.22390333,  5.18910776])
```

Note that by default this computes the robust estimate of the standard deviation assuming a normal distribution by scaling the result a scaling factor; from `help`:

```
Signature: robust.mad(a, 
                      c=0.67448975019608171, 
                      axis=0, 
                      center=<function median at 0x10ba6e5f0>)
```

The version in `R` makes a similar normalization. If you don't want this, obviously just set `c=1`.

(An earlier comment mentioned this being in `statsmodels.robust.scale`. The implementation is in `statsmodels/robust/scale.py` (see [github](https://github.com/statsmodels/statsmodels/tree/master/statsmodels/robust)) but the `robust` package does not export `scale`, rather it exports the public functions in `scale.py` explicitly.)

Comment: Just note that this is **median**, not **mean** absolute deviation (and the latter was in the question)

Comment: @sfjac Good one. Can you please explain how the scaling is done to a array based on the constant `c=0.67448975019608171`? It would really help understand it better. I wasn't able to understand it clearly from the github page. It would really help.

Comment: @SaiKumar This constant is chosen so that if the data sample is drawn from a Gaussian population N(mu, sigma), the resulting statistic will be a robust estimate of sigma.

Comment: @sfjac I didn't get that, what do you mean by robust estimate of sigma. Can you explain how the calculation is being done here. If you do `robust.mad(a, axis=1, c=1)` you get ouput as `[1.5,3.5]` and this is the correct `MAD` but why do we use `c=0.67 you get array as `[2.2239,5.1891]`. I want to know how it's being done. Does it multiple it with constant? I'm sorry I'm new to python.

Comment: Right. It computes the median of the absolute deviations from the sample median. This is a robust estimate of distribution width that is independent of the distribution. If the data is Gaussian, this value will be approximately equal to the standard deviation of the Gaussian divided by 0.67. By default the function rescales the result by this 0.67, and returns a statistic that is approximately equal to the standard deviation.

Answer (score 17):

It looks like scipy.stats.models was [removed](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/commit/174e708f823162bb56248c63ee1985f672797503#diff-34) in august 2008 due to insufficient baking.  Development has migrated to [`statsmodels`](http://statsmodels.sourceforge.net/).

Comment: Yes, most of the old stats.models was the basis for scikits.statsmodels, after a lot of cleanup. MAD is at the bottom page here http://statsmodels.sourceforge.net/rlm.html as part of robust estimation of linear models but I never used it standalone since it's just a few lines.

Comment: The above link is broken, so I found [this one](http://statsmodels.sourceforge.net/devel/generated/statsmodels.robust.scale.mad.html?highlight=median%20absolute%20deviation) on the statsmodels documentation.

Answer (score 11):

If you enjoy working in [Pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/) (like I do), it has a useful [function for the mean absolute deviation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.mad.html):

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame()
df['a'] = [1, 1, 2, 2, 4, 6, 9]
df['a'].mad()
```

Output: 2.3673469387755106

Comment: This is the best answer.  Weird that this isn't built in to numpy... but since once can't have pandas without numpy one should really use pandas anyways!

Answer (score 4):

It's not the scipy version, but here's an implementation of the MAD using masked arrays to ignore bad values:
http://code.google.com/p/agpy/source/browse/trunk/agpy/mad.py

Edit: A more recent version is available [here](https://github.com/keflavich/agpy/commits/master).

Edit 2: There's also a version in astropy [here](http://docs.astropy.org/en/stable/api/astropy.stats.median_absolute_deviation.html).

Answer (score 3):

I'm just learning Python and Numpy, but here is the code I wrote to check my 7th grader's math homework which wanted the M(ean)AD of 2 sets of numbers:

Data in Numpy matrix rows:

```
import numpy as np

>>> a = np.matrix( [ [ 80, 76, 77, 78, 79, 81, 76, 77, 79, 84, 75, 79, 76, 78 ], \\    
... [ 66, 69, 76, 72, 79, 77, 74, 77, 71, 79, 74, 66, 67, 73 ] ], dtype=float )    
>>> matMad = np.mean( np.abs( np.tile( np.mean( a, axis=1 ), ( 1, a.shape[1] ) ) - a ), axis=1 )    
>>> matMad    
matrix([[ 1.81632653],
        [ 3.73469388]])
```

Data in Numpy 1D arrays:

```
>>> a1 = np.array( [ 80, 76, 77, 78, 79, 81, 76, 77, 79, 84, 75, 79, 76, 78 ], dtype=float )    
>>> a2 = np.array( [ 66, 69, 76, 72, 79, 77, 74, 77, 71, 79, 74, 66, 67, 73 ], dtype=float )    
>>> madA1 = np.mean( np.abs( np.tile( np.mean( a1 ), ( 1, len( a1 ) ) ) - a1 ) )    
>>> madA2 = np.mean( np.abs( np.tile( np.mean( a2 ), ( 1, len( a2 ) ) ) - a2 ) )    
>>> madA1, madA2    
(1.816326530612244, 3.7346938775510199)
```

Answer (score 3):

Using `numpy` only:

```
def meanDeviation(numpyArray):
    mean = np.mean(numpyArray)
    f = lambda x: abs(x - mean)
    vf = np.vectorize(f)
    return (np.add.reduce(vf(numpyArray))) / len(numpyArray)
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm using:

```
from math import fabs

a = [1, 1, 2, 2, 4, 6, 9]

median = sorted(a)[len(a)//2]

for b in a:
    mad = fabs(b - median)
    print b,mad
```

Comment: This does not work when the number of sample is an even number.

Answer (score 0):

Do not want to be misleaded, the mad is now in scipy.stats:

https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.median_abs_deviation.html

> Compute the median absolute deviation of the data along the given axis.

Comment: Are you saying it's now part of the library?

Comment: @Frank it isn't entirely clear what you are trying to say. Please consider editing your answer and adding more details...

Comment: @Scratte Yes it is in scipy.stats

Comment: This is the **median** absolute deviation, not the **mean**

Answer (score 0):

You can change the center function in `scipy.stats.median_abs_deviation` from median to mean (https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.median_abs_deviation.html)

```
scipy.stats.median_abs_deviation(values, center=numpy.mean)
```