# L1 norm instead of L2 norm for cost function in regression model

Tags: python, machine-learning, regression, least-squares

I was wondering if there's a function in Python that would do the same job as `scipy.linalg.lstsq` but uses “least absolute deviations” regression instead of “least squares” regression (OLS). I want to use the `L1` norm, instead of the `L2` norm.

In fact, I have 3d points, which I want the best-fit plane of them. The common approach is by the least square method like this Github [link](https://gist.github.com/amroamroamro/1db8d69b4b65e8bc66a6). But It's known that this doesn't give the best fit always, especially when we have interlopers in our set of data. And it's better to calculate the least absolute deviation. The difference between the two methods is explained more [here](http://www.chioka.in/differences-between-the-l1-norm-and-the-l2-norm-least-absolute-deviations-and-least-squares/).

It'll not be solved by functions such as MAD since it's an `Ax = b` matrix equations and requires loops to minimizes the results. I want to know if anyone knows of a relevant function in Python - probably in a linear algebra package - that would calculate “least absolute deviations” regression?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Where can I find mad (mean absolute deviation) in scipy?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8930370/where-can-i-find-mad-mean-absolute-deviation-in-scipy)

Comment: @Joel this does not appear to be a duplicate of the linked question. While both deal with the MAD, this question goes one step further to use it as an optimisation objective, which is not what the linked question is about.

Comment: @N.Wouda both questions ask about how to use MAD in Python. How does the question I linked go "one step further" in dealing with an optimization objective?

Comment: Would you please post a link to the data?

Comment: @Joel OP wrote "if there's a function in Python that would the same job as `scipy.linalg.lstsq` but minimizes least absolute deviation instead of least square deviation". This is not what `sm.robust.mad` does: it just computes the deviation, it does not optimise over the parameters. That's why I feel this question goes one step further, and should thus not be closed as a duplicate.

Comment: @Joel No this question is not a duplicate, I'll explain it more.

Comment: @N. Wouda yes exactly as you said it's finding the best values, do you know of any relevant function in Python?

Comment: If all else fails you can `scipy.optimize.minimize` yourself.

Comment: If you use a non-linear solver, it will require initial parameter estimates as a starting point. One possibility to obtain good starting parameters is to pass the parameters from scipy.linalg.lstsq, these should be close and the least-squares linear algebra will run very quickly.

Answer (score 11):

This is not so difficult to roll yourself, using `scipy.optimize.minimize` and a custom `cost_function`.

Let us first import the necessities,

```
from scipy.optimize import minimize
import numpy as np
```

And define a custom cost function (and a convenience wrapper for obtaining the fitted values),

```
def fit(X, params):
    return X.dot(params)


def cost_function(params, X, y):
    return np.sum(np.abs(y - fit(X, params)))
```

Then, if you have some `X` (design matrix) and `y` (observations), we can do the following,

```
output = minimize(cost_function, x0, args=(X, y))

y_hat = fit(X, output.x)
```

Where `x0` is some suitable initial guess for the optimal parameters (you could take @JamesPhillips' advice here, and use the fitted parameters from an OLS approach).

In any case, when test-running with a somewhat contrived example,

```
X = np.asarray([np.ones((100,)), np.arange(0, 100)]).T
y = 10 + 5 * np.arange(0, 100) + 25 * np.random.random((100,))
```

I find,

```
      fun: 629.4950595335436
 hess_inv: array([[  9.35213468e-03,  -1.66803210e-04],
       [ -1.66803210e-04,   1.24831279e-05]])
      jac: array([  0.00000000e+00,  -1.52587891e-05])
  message: 'Optimization terminated successfully.'
     nfev: 144
      nit: 11
     njev: 36
   status: 0
  success: True
        x: array([ 19.71326758,   5.07035192])
```

And,

```
fig = plt.figure()
ax = plt.axes()

ax.plot(y, 'o', color='black')
ax.plot(y_hat, 'o', color='blue')

plt.show()
```

With the fitted values in blue, and the data in black.

[image]

Comment: Have you ever worked with quantile regression [function](http://www.statsmodels.org/dev/examples/notebooks/generated/quantile_regression.html)? I've asked around and my seniors said "The LAD model is a special case of quantile regression where q=0.5." I wonder how different these two functions are and how different their results could be.

Comment: @Sara.Eft I've heard of it, but I've never used it before. I suspect you'll want to use [`statsmodels.regression.quantile_regression.QuantReg`](https://www.statsmodels.org/dev/generated/statsmodels.regression.quantile_regression.QuantReg.html) instead, mostly because it has more features, using `q = 0.5` (as in the manual there also). I had not realised quantile regression could be used as well.

Answer (score 2):

You can solve your problem using scipy.minimize function. You have to set the function you want to minimize (in our case a plane with the form Z= aX + bY + c) and the error function (L1 norm) then run the minimizer with some starting value.

```
import numpy as np
import scipy.linalg
from scipy.optimize import minimize
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def fit(X, params):
    # 3d Plane Z = aX + bY + c
    return X.dot(params[:2]) + params[2]

def cost_function(params, X, y):
    # L1- norm
    return np.sum(np.abs(y - fit(X, params)))
```

We generate 3d points

```
# Generating  3-dim points
mean = np.array([0.0,0.0,0.0])
cov = np.array([[1.0,-0.5,0.8], [-0.5,1.1,0.0], [0.8,0.0,1.0]])
data = np.random.multivariate_normal(mean, cov, 50)
```

Last we run the minimizer

```
output = minimize(cost_function, [0.5,0.5,0.5], args=(np.c_[data[:,0], data[:,1]], data[:, 2]))
y_hat = fit(np.c_[data[:,0], data[:,1]], output.x)

X,Y = np.meshgrid(np.arange(min(data[:,0]), max(data[:,0]), 0.5),    np.arange(min(data[:,1]), max(data[:,1]), 0.5))
XX = X.flatten()
YY = Y.flatten()


# # evaluate it on grid
Z = output.x[0]*X + output.x[1]*Y + output.x[2]
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(10,10))
ax = fig.gca(projection='3d')
ax.plot_surface(X, Y, Z, rstride=1, cstride=1, alpha=0.2)
ax.scatter(data[:,0], data[:,1], data[:,2], c='r')
plt.show()
```

[image]

Note: I  have used the previous response code and the [code](https://gist.github.com/amroamroamro/1db8d69b4b65e8bc66a6) from the github as a start