# scipy.optimize.minimize can't find least square solution

Tags: machine-learning, scipy, regression, scipy-optimize, scipy-optimize-minimize

My intention was to solve the l1 error fitting problem using scipy.optimize as suggested in [L1 norm instead of L2 norm for cost function in regression model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51883058/l1-norm-instead-of-l2-norm-for-cost-function-in-regression-model), but I keep getting the wrong solution, so I debugged using least square which we know how to get a closed-form expression:

```
n=10
d=2
A = np.random.rand(n,d)
x = np.random.rand(d,1)
b = np.dot(A, x)
x_hat = np.linalg.lstsq(A, b)[0]
print(np.linalg.norm(np.dot(A, x_hat)-b))


def fit(X, params):
    return X.dot(params)

def cost_function(params, X, y):
    return np.linalg.norm(y - fit(X, params))

x0 = np.zeros((d,1))

output = minimize(cost_function, x0, args=(A, b))

y_hat = fit(A, output.x)
print(np.linalg.norm(y_hat-b))
print(output)
```

The output is:

```
4.726604209672303e-16
2.2714597315189407
      fun: 2.2714597315189407
 hess_inv: array([[ 0.19434496, -0.1424377 ],
       [-0.1424377 ,  0.16718703]])
      jac: array([ 3.57627869e-07, -2.98023224e-08])
  message: 'Optimization terminated successfully.'
     nfev: 32
      nit: 4
     njev: 8
   status: 0
  success: True
        x: array([0.372247  , 0.32633966])
```

which looks super weird because it can't even solve the l2 regression? Am I making stupid mistakes here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is due to mismatching shapes. [Minimize](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.minimize.html#scipy-optimize-minimize)'s `x0` and the iterates have shape `(n,)`. So when `params` has shape `(n,)`, `fit(X,params)` will be shape `(n,)` while your `y` has shape `(n,1)`. Thus, the expression `y-fit(X,params)` has shape `(n,n)` due to numpy's implicit broadcasting. And in consequence `np.linalg.norm` returns the frobenius matrix norm instead of the euclidean vector norm.

Solution: change your cost function to:

```
def cost_function(params, X, y):
    return np.linalg.norm(y - fit(X, params.reshape(d,1)))
```