# MatLab mad() vs SciPy.Stats median_abs_deviation() differences

Tags: python, matlab, scipy, mean

I am converting some MatLab code to Python, and cannot solve why the results I am getting are different.

In MatLab, the `mad` function on the input `x = [1, 2, 4, 3, 7, 2, 1, 3, 2, 1]` yields a result of `1.32`. However, when using the equiv function in `SciPy.Stats`, that is, `median_abs_deviation`, I get a different result of `1.0`.

My code, exactly is:

Matlab:

```matlab
x = [1, 2, 4, 3, 7, 2, 1, 3, 2, 1];
mdat = mad(x)
```

Python:

```py
from scipy import stats

x = np.array([1, 2, 4, 3, 7, 2, 1, 3, 2, 1])
print(stats.median_abs_deviation(x))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default in Matlab is to compute the **mean** absolute deviation. If you want the median absolute deviation, then the command is `mad(x,1)`.

If you're interested in computing the mean absolute deviation in Python, see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8930370/2476977).